# Issue with aggregate power BI SUM

Tags: powerbi, sum, dax

I'm trying to replicate a business calculation that exists in my environment on PowerBI, but I'm not getting what I expect as a result.

I have 2 tables that I made as an example and replicate the real life problem.

Table Sales:

```
dateSold      Sector    Idsale  NPS
01/12/2021    A         1       good
01/11/2021    A         2       bad
01/11/2021    A         3       good
01/11/2021    B         4       bad
01/10/2021    A         5       bad
01/10/2021    B         6       good
01/10/2021    B         7       good
01/09/2021    A         8       good
01/09/2021    A         9       good
01/09/2021    A         10      good
```

And Weights table:

```
SECTOR  Weight
A       0,7
B       0,3
```

I created some fields to do my math and they do what I expect, but the last field doesnt. I did a COUNT for GOOD and BAD and total values on the field NPS using this method:

```
QuantityGOOD = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA(Sales[Idsale])
    , DATESINPERIOD(Sales[dateSold], SELECTEDVALUE(Sales[dateSold]), -3, MONTH)
    , Sales[NPS] == "good"
)
```

Then Created a field with the math using my fields:

```
NPSCalculated = 
[QuantityGOOD] / [QuantityTotal] - [QuantityBad] / [QuantityTotal]
```

Then in the last step I have to multiply this value by the weights in the other table, and I tryed this:

```
FinalValue = 
CALCULATE(
SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(Sales ,Sales[dateSold], weights[Sector]),
    [NPSCalculated] * 
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE(weights[weight]))))
```

But this code cuts out the values of the sector A that exists in the previous months and doesnt exist in the target month. It returns the sum without the part missing.

```
SaleDate    Sector  bad   good  total   NPS     weight  FinalValue
2021-12     A       2     2     4       0       0,7     0
2021-12     B       1     2     3       0,333   0,3     0,1
```

I need to get the results of the column FinalValue as above (did it in excel for 2021-12 only), but instead I get only the fist line on PBI. Can you guys help me?

Comment: If you use a matrix for the output you will not see the second row because for 2021-12-01 'B' doesn't exist. You can get a matrix with 2 rows for your data model only if you put Sector column first, or add a calendar table, mark it as a date table for and link it with model. If you just want to get the matrix with no changes in you data model. then you can do it if 1- put 'Sector' as rows in the matrix, 2-change all columns to measures.

Comment: I altered the answer for matrix with sector in rows

Answer (score 0):

measureSalesDate :

```
 SalesDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Sales[dateSold]),ALL(Sales[Sector]) -- last Visible date in a current context
```

measurebad/good :

```
bad||good=
VAR lastVisibleSalesDate=
        CALCULATETABLE(LASTDATE(Sales[dateSold]),ALL(Sales[Sector]))
         -- CALCULATETABLE, because  LASTDATE() returns the value as table
RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
        COUNT(Sales[Idsale])
        ,DATESINPERIOD(Sales[dateSold], lastVisibleSalesDate, -3, MONTH)
        ,Sales[NPS] = "good"
    )
```

measureNPSCalculated :

```
NPSCalculated =
VAR lastVisibleSalesDate=
       CALCULATETABLE(LASTDATE(Sales[dateSold]),ALL(Sales[Sector]))  
VAR QuantityTotal= 
        CALCULATE(
            COUNT(Sales[Idsale])
            ,DATESINPERIOD(Sales[dateSold], lastVisibleSalesDate, -3, MONTH)
            ,ALL(Sales[NPS])
        )
RETURN 
    ([QuantityGOOD]-[QuantityBad])/QuantityTotal -- it's equal to yours
```

measureWeight :

```
 Weight=SELECTEDVALUE(weights[weight])
```

measureFinalValue:

```
FinalValue = [NPSCalculated] * [Weight]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply @mik, but this is stil not providing the expected result. the output for FINALVALUE changed to 0,58. I see what you did and tried some changes on it but without success. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the following steps are followed
   Click on File-->Get data-->and import the required data-->then load the data into PowerBI
   [Loading The Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysUx3.png)

Make sure that the dataset is loaded perfectly.

2. Next, you need to create a new date table for this visual via
   Calendar = CALENDAR(MIN('Sales'[dateSold]), MAX('Sales'[dateSold]))
   Then add a calculated column named month like the below.

[calendar table creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XR6t.png)

3. In the table visual, replace [dateSold] with [Month], which will let the table visual get a Cartesian product of [month] and [SECTOR].
4. And change the parameter in your measure DATESINPERIOD(). Replace the dateSold column with the new date column.
   DATESINPERIOD('Sales'[dateSold], MIN('Calendar'[Date]),-3,MONTH))
   [dates in period](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6cdo.png)

I need to get the results of the column FinalValue as above (did it in excel for 2021-12 only), but instead I get only the first line on PBI. Can you guys help me?

Then in the last step, I have to multiply this value by the weights in the other table, and I tried this:

FinalValue =
CALCULATE(
SUMX(
SUMMARIZE(Sales ,Sales[dateSold], weights[Sector]),
[NPSCalculated] *
CALCULATE(
AVERAGE(weights[weight]))))

Instead of this if we use this code then the expected output will be shown as the result
FinalValue =
VAR _s =
ADDCOLUMNS (
CROSSJOIN ( VALUES ( 'Calendar'[Month] ), 'Weight' ),
"final", [Weight] * [NPSCalculated]
)
RETURN
SUMX ( _s, [final] )
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCJhR.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).